# How to play a sound all the time while a picturebox is moving C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to play a sound all the time while a picturebox is moving using keydown event. My code is this:

```
    private bool soundPlaying = false;
    private SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(@"Sounds/Step.wav");

    private void PlaySound(bool start)
    {
        if (start)
        {
            if (!soundPlaying)
            {
                soundPlaying = true;
                player.PlayLooping();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            soundPlaying = false;
            player.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void Joc_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        {
            PlaySound(true);
        }
    }

    private void Joc_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Joc joc = new Joc();
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        {
            joc.keyPressW(velocity, gameboard, ColonistList, StoneListMain, treeList, treeFHD, treeHD, stoneFHD, stoneHD, stoneLooted, killedMob, Ship, Wolf, Distance, inventoryButton, openInventory, LifeBarStroke, InnerLifeBar, WolfHealthStroke);
            PlaySound(false);
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S) joc.keyPressS(velocity, gameboard, ColonistList, StoneListMain, treeList, smallStoneList, treeFHD, treeHD, stoneFHD, stoneHD, stoneLooted, killedMob, Ship, Wolf, Distance, inventoryButton, openInventory, LifeBarStroke, InnerLifeBar, WolfHealthStroke);
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D) joc.keyPressD(velocity, gameboard, ColonistList, StoneListMain, treeList, smallStoneList, treeFHD, treeHD, stoneFHD, stoneHD, stoneLooted, killedMob, Ship, Wolf, Distance, inventoryButton, openInventory, LifeBarStroke, InnerLifeBar, WolfHealthStroke);
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A) joc.keyPressA(velocity, gameboard, ColonistList, StoneListMain, treeList, smallStoneList, treeFHD, treeHD, stoneFHD, stoneHD, stoneLooted, killedMob, Ship, Wolf, Distance, inventoryButton, openInventory, LifeBarStroke, InnerLifeBar, WolfHealthStroke);
    }
```

In the class "Joc" are the walking functions. In this moment, this code is playing one time the sound when I walk the first pixel and when I stopped pressing the key it plays again the sound. How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On most systems, when you hold down a key, you'll start to get [repeated keystrokes after a small delay](https://www.dummies.com/computers/pcs/set-your-keyboards-repeat-delay-and-repeat-rate/).  So you're going to get many, many keydown events...and you'll end up calling `PlayLooping()` many times as well.  This will cause it to reset each time, resulting in choppy sound, or it may reset so quickly that it will seem as if it isn't even playing at all.

To solve this, setup a boolean that tracks whether the sound is already playing or not, so that you only call `PlayLooping()` once.  You should probably also move your `SoundPlayer` instance out to class level, as there is no need to keep reloading it every time.  So on keydown we call `PlaySound(true)`, while on keyup we call `PlaySound(false)`, as shown below (simplified code for clarity):

```
private bool soundPlaying = false;
private SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(@"Sounds/Step.wav");

private void Joc_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
    {
        PlaySound(true);                
    }
}

private void PlaySound(bool start)
{
    if (start)
    {
        if (!soundPlaying)
        {
            soundPlaying = true;
            player.PlayLooping();                    
        }                
    }
    else
    {
        soundPlaying = false;
        player.Stop();
    }
}

private void Joc_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
    {
        PlaySound(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works in a way. It plays after I finished walking. Can you help me ?

Comment: We'd have to see your updated code to figure it out.  You're not still using the Timer are you?  The idea is that you start the sound in the keydown event and stop it in the keyup event.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  Looks like you had true/false backwards.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's understand how we are playing a sound.
It's quite simple, right? As you wrote above, you need to call `player.Play();`.
But does that mean that sound will play continuously? The answer is no, it will not.

> How to play a sound all the time while a picturebox is moving C#

So how to make the sound repeatedly play until we want to stop it?
To make that happen, you need to use [SoundPlayer.PlayLooping()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer.playlooping?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) method, but before that, my suggestion here is instead of instantiating sound player object in the `timer1_Tick` create a class field.

Now, let's keep it very simple, you want to play sound as long as the `KeyDown` is calling or let's say another way until you don't release the button, right?

---

What you need here is to do two things:

1. Call `player.PlayLooping` on `KeyDown` or `KeyPress`.
2. Call [SoundPlayer.Stop()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer.stop?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) method like with the `player.Stop()` call on `KeyUp` Event.